# How to display images in datalist using database images field value

Tags: asp.net

I need the pictures to the address stored in the database, I would show up inside Datalist
How to display image in Datalist?

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: Always paste what you have tried here so that the other have a better idea and could help you more mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the datalist to your data source considering that the field with picture path is called "Pic_Path" here is the aspx page

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" >
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="Image1" ID="Image1" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Pic_Path") %>' runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: این مشکل حل شد ولی موقع اجرا این خطا رو میده Error 5 'ASP.adinebook_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.adinebook_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you have probably created a DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged method and then deleted it manually is that the case?
if true select your control goto property page check the event tab make sure the selectedindexchanged is not assigned

Comment: <asp:Image ID="Image1"  
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' runat="server" />

Comment: check the path.Probably you need to append something to the path you get from database

Comment: you have to pass a correct full path or relative path to the image like "http://yourwebsite\yourAppDir\Images\image1.jpg" or "~\images\image1.jpg" which means root\images\image1.jpg

Comment: i gave instead, the name address field photo the database.is it true?

Comment: thanks , i think first should images upload into a folder in  appdir and the next use url image for image path